# Regarding Kivy in Python

Tags: python, android, kivy

My problem is a bit complicated and not technical. There is this project that I and my team mates are working on for a competition. We are creating a voice assistant in Python for medical fields. All the work in Python programming (core) has been done.

But we want to create an app. The framework we chose is Kivy. But none of us is an app developer and does not know any of it. We have been looking for some good tutorials or books which could help us but none did, the Kivy documentation is way too complex.

If you know Kivy and can help us to create an interface (a simple one, just a logo in the middle which will keep on listening to commands like Google Assistant), or to connect a Kivy file to the main Python program, kindly help.

Comment: I agree that Kivy has very limited resources available as of now and it's documentation is complex, but I would rather say why use kivy ? You can develop your app in android and then make necessary integrations. Also if you want help in kivy, refer Sentdex, Derek Banas (Youtube Channel), then the whole documentation will start making sense. Also I would hardly suggest anyone to use kivy ever for android apps. Would suggest react native rather for app if you want lightweight stuffs. And integrating js with python shouldn't be difficult. Don't waste time on kivy, I had wasted lots of time on it.

Comment: check out https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCUd2LiAwrk_QqXc4KgLZu-Q

Comment: http://inclem.net/2019/12/19/kivy/getting_started_with_kivy/

Comment: You mention creating an `app`. Is that a PC `app`, an android `app`, an iPhone `app`?

Comment: Using kivy as frontend for android apps when your base code is python shouldn't be a big issue. You can check if https://github.com/kivy/audiostream is helping you. Start with a hello world. When you can deploy it successfully half of the way is done.

Comment: This is far too broad, and is not on-topic for Stack Overflow. Questions should be limited in scope to one thing, and not be seeking free work from readers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example of how you can get started:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder

# this builds the GUI screen with just a logo
theRoot = Builder.load_string('''
RelativeLayout:
    Image:
        source: 'path/to/logo/image'    # path to logo image
        allow_stretch: True     # allow thw logo to be stretched
        keep_ratio: True        # do not distort the logo
        size_hint: 0.25, 0.25   # make the logo take up 25% of the screen in both x and y directions
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}    # position the logo in the center of the scene
''')

# this is the actual App class
class JustALogoApp(App):
    def build(self):
        # call a method to start your real code
        Clock.schedule_once(self.start_listening)

        # return the root of your app display (created above)
        return theRoot

    def start_listening(self, dt):
        print('start running python code here')
        print('it must be started using another thread or another process')
        print('the main thread is reserved for the GUI')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # actually start the app
    JustALogoApp().run()
```

You may want to add some `Buttons`, like a start and/or stop `Button`.